# Android: Detect user inactivity / Detect (softkeyboard) keyboard input

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, user-inactivity

I want to detect "user inactivity" in my Android app. To be more precise: I want to detect if the user has NOT done any interaction with my app (touching the screen, scrolling, input texts ...) for a specific time. Technically I use a timer that is reseted on each (user) interaction.

In my activity, I override the *onUserInteraction* method to detect interactions like scrolling, touching the screen ...

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction(){
    resetInactiveTimer();
}
```

Unfortunately, onUserInteraction is not called when the user interacts with the soft keyboard. I think the reason is, that the soft keyboard is not part of my Activity.

For the edit texts in my app I use *TextWatcher* and the *onTextChanged* method which works fine. But my app also contain a WebView that loads arbitrary web pages. Of course some web pages could contain input fields and I do not know how to detect that the user interacts with the soft keyboard to edit those text fields.

Comment: u got any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Still interested in this?

Your activity implements `KeyEvent.Callback`, so you can override `onKeyDown`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    resetInactiveTimer();
    return false;
}
```

Alternatively, (in the most common circumstance) if the key is pressed with the cursor in an `EditText` or similar, you will need implement an `OnKeyListener` and use the `onKey` method to call `resetInactiveTimer();`

Comment: Input Methods are not required to sent key events. In fact jelly beans softkeyboard does not send any key event when backspace is pressed.

Comment: But here issue is that onUserInteraction is not called when you are typing in edittext. Also if I want to use onKeyDown  or onKey, I have to set key press listener to each and every edittext. Is there any general option where I can track any keypress event from soft keyboard ?

Comment: Not working. Activity's onKeyDown isn't invoked when I type smth in edit text